# Workbench Email - Slowing down Add Edit

Tags: nodes, workbench

I've configured workbench as per tutorial, everything works fine until i've handful of users but when I imported about 7000 users (authors) and when I open Add or Edit content type form for editorial it take more than a minute to load and sometime throws timeout error.

I'm showing Author field (auto-suggest and not dropdown) on content type add / edit form.

pulling out my hair to understand the cause. when I disable workbench email module everything becomes normal, page loads in less than 5 secs.

appreciate any answer or hint to solve this issue. is this due to any mis-configuration of workbench access module?

Comment: As starting point check drupal error logs and check if you have this patch https://www.drupal.org/node/2464969 applied

Comment: thank you for the reply. there was nothing in drupal logs, however i'll check on the patch and see if that makes a difference. 

having said that, this patch is for access module, but for load time increases when I've the workbench email module active, is this patch code somehow related to email module too?

Comment: patch is specific to workbench access module and has nothing to do with email module. To find out performance intensive function running you can setup a profiling tool like XHProf, it will you detailed info of what all functions are called and what it took for their execution.